# Javascript Onclick Event automatically execute

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I add some buttons dynamically with javascript depending on the value of a select box. This is the code for the button:

```
    var cancel = document.createElement("button");
    cancel.innerHTML = "Cancel";
    cancel.type = "button";
    cancel.onclick = location.reload();
    container.appendChild(cancel);
```

This button is added to a modal dialog and should reload the page when it is clicked. If the function with which the button is added to the modal dialog is executed, the onclick event is also executed although the button was not clicked. Can anybody help me please? Thanks

Comment: `location.reload();` will execeute immediatly. Omit brackets `()` or wrap it in function `() => location.reload();`.

Comment: @M1K1O's comment is the solution.

Comment: @M1K1O: Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: The recommended method is `cancel.addEventListener("click",location.reload)` or `cancel.addEventListener("click",function() { location.reload(); })` - note where the brackets are used here and where not

Comment: `location.reload();` return nothing....